# Determine last page in Solr using cursorMark

Tags: solr

I am building an API that allows for searching on a number of fields in solr with pagination. It returns cursorMark from the solr results in the API response for users to use in their next query.

I'm following the Google AIP for pagination which requires returning a blank string when there are no more results left however Solr will keep returning the same cursor.

I'm looking for a simple solution that doesn't involve keeping state on the server or needing to make multiple requests. If I knew the position of the page in the total list of results I could determine if the page is the last, but I'm not able to access this.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: `if current_cursor == retrieved_current_cursor: return ""`? There is no server side state necessary; if the cursor you're sending in is the same that gets returned, you've reached the last page. Not having "position of the page" is the thing that makes cursorMarks work fast.

Comment: When i've tried this, `retriever_current_cursor` is different than the `current cursor`. Only if you do one more search with the cursor returned at the last page,`retriever_current_cursor`, will it keep returning the same cursor for that comparison to work.
 
I managed to get around this by encoding the number of paginated results in another token.

Comment: Yes, you'll have to have one final request that tells you that there is no more documents to iterate over.